# Objective C: What is the impact of not including <UIActionSheetDelegate> protocol in header file?

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am implementing a action sheet and found that the code works even without including the  protocol in the header file. Is there a impact in no including it?

Thanks

Zhen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no runtime impact*, but including the protocol specification:

1. allows the compiler to verify that you have implemented all required methods (e.g. forgetting implementing `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with a UITableViewDataSource will give a warning), and
2. allows the library writer to restrict types to delegates that can surely respond to the expected methods (e.g. assigning a non-UIActionSheetDelegate to an `id<UIActionSheetDelegate>` will give a warning)

<sub>(*: Technically the list of protocols can be queried in runtime, so including it may change some runtime behavior, but this situation is rare.)</sub>